# Selector for finding an element by both class name and text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

What's the selector for finding an element by both class name and text?  For example:

```
<div class="a1">some text</div>
<div class="a1">some other text</div>
<div class="a2">some text</div>
```

Suppose I only care about the div element with class "a1" and "some text".

Thanks in advance,
Alvaro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [:contains()](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector like this:

```
$('.a1:contains("some text")');
```

Comment: Neat... I didn't know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` with parameter selector `"[class='a1']"`, array literal and spread element to cast `NodeList` to `Array`, `Array.prototype.find()` to check and match `.textContent` property of element to variable or string literal.

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll("[class=a1]")]
.find(({textContent}) => textContent === "some text")
.style.color = "green";
```

```html
<div class="a1">some text</div>
<div class="a1">some other text</div>
<div class="a2">some text</div>
```